Elasticbeanstalk logs into the CloudWatch [CloudWatch treat single line as a log]
I’m working on a Spring application deployed on AWS Elastic Beanstalk as a JAR. The application logs are written to /aws/elasticbeanstalk/xxx/var/log/web.stdout.log and sent to Amazon CloudWatch Logs.
Problem:
Log Aggregation: Logs that span multiple lines are sent to CloudWatch as separate entries, making it difficult to analyze complete log entries. For example, when an error occurs that spans several lines, each line is logged as a separate entry in CloudWatch instead of grouping them into a single cohesive log entry.
I attempted to configure the CloudWatch Agent using .ebextensions files, but nothing happened. (I was archivded my jar with .ebextensions file and i deployed it in my eb enviroment)
my .ebextensions file
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/pre/01_cloudwatch_logs.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash
      yum install -y awslogs
      service awslogs start
      chkconfig awslogs on

  "/etc/awslogs/config/awslogs.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      [general]
      state_file = /var/lib/awslogs/agent-state

      [/var/log/web.stdout.log]
      log_group_name = /aws/elasticbeanstalk/xxx/var/log/web.stdout.log
      log_stream_name = {instance_id}
      file = /var/log/web.stdout.log
      datetime_format = %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ
      multi_line_start_pattern = "^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z\s+(INFO|ERROR|WARN|DEBUG)"

I want to see that error as single log in the cloudwatch not 4 separate logs.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.myproject.Book.getTitle(Book.java:16)
        at com.example.myproject.Author.getBookTitles(Author.java:25)
        at com.example.myproject.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:14)


can you share a log line starting with the pattern you configured in multi_line_start_pattern ?

2024-08-31T23:08:23.892+02:00  INFO 33724 --- [           main] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
it's default spring log format
